# Starting a list of processes with XX.MainModule.FileName

Tags: c#, process

I have a program with a checkbox which allows users to select as many currently running processes as they want, and monitor them and then restart them if they go down.

I have the monitoring part done, it checks if they are in

```
Process.GetProcesses()
```

every X seconds.

then displays:

```
  listBox1.Items.Add(itemChecked + @" " + @"is running" + @" " + DateTime.Now);
```

but if they are not running I'm trying to get the process file path like this:

```
foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)

            {
                var retVal = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName == itemChecked.ToString());

                if (retVal.Equals(true))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(itemChecked + @" " + @"is running" + @" " + DateTime.Now);
                }

                else if (retVal.Equals(false))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(itemChecked + @" " + @"is not running, attempting to start" + @" " + DateTime.Now);
                    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName(itemChecked.ToString());

                    foreach (Process theProcess in processList)
                    {
                     Process.Start(theProcess.MainModule.FileName.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

With this code nothing happens if they are not running apart from telling me it's not running. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your sure the process is never spawned (if it is down) as opposed to comes down again? How did you confirm this? Does the process have any arguments? Does your process have sufficient privileges to start the process?

Comment: I have been doing some more reading and i think my program doesn't have permissions to view the file paths. Is the a way i can tell it to run as admin?

Comment: Your query produces an `IEnumerable<Process>`.  It is never equal to true or false.  Hard to guess what was intended, consider enumerating it with foreach.